# What order do images get downloaded in on your site?

Tags: html, css, image, browser

Do images get downloaded in the order they are displayed in the markup or is there an alpha-numeric order that items that are displayed get downloaded?

Im wondering because I'd like to order my site asset sprites to be downloaded before the featured images.

Comment: I don't think there are any *guarantees* on the order in which they'll be downloaded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Difficult to say, there are images in the markup and images in the CSS.  There aren't really any rules, it's down to the browser.

If they were requested in source order, there's no guarantee the response (all the image data) will be received in the same order they were requested.  A browser can make several requests simultaneously, so it depends on where the image is being served from, and the size of the image.

Also they could be already cached, I think you might be overly fussing about the unnecessary.

You can experiment or look at some JavaScript preloader routines or something, but honestly, it's not the kind of thing to worry about.  Users are used to this kind of experience.

The simplest implementation would be to hide all these images (using JavaScript so that non-JS isn't affected) and wait for the page's onload event, then you can use a JavaScript timer to make the images appear in the order you want them to appear in.

The onload event fires once all the associated page artefacts have finished loading, sometimes this can never happen (hopefully rarely), or take an unbearably long time.  Well, you could also have a time-out to trigger the onload event handler as fallback, just in case this happens, then just display what you have.  This is the kind of thing that would lead me to not bother doing anything fancy at all, and just keep things simple.

If the problem is that your page is reflowing as the images are loading, then that is because you haven't specified the dimensions for the image placeholder (e.g. width and height attribute of the IMG element).

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423623/order-of-loading-images-in-html-and-css

Comment: Great point with onload. I never used that before, so this is enlightening. Thanks Lee!

Answer (score 1):

Firefox **seems** load images in the order they are displayed in the markup. I believe Chrome and Internet just do the same.

You can just test by yourself using Firebug in Firefox or the Chrome console.

Comment: If you think they always do so, you haven’t done sufficient testing.